# Qt5, Visual Studio 2012 Express and OpenMp. How to?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, openmp

I am trying to compile http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/ raytracer using Qt5 and Visual Studio 2012 compiler.

It works Okay but when I try to use openmp by adding

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
LIBS += -fopenmp
```

to project.pro
, Qt says that /fopenmp is not recognized and ignored.

When I compile using VS command

```
cl /c /O2 /EHsc /openmp main.cpp
```

it works and I get a program 3 times faster then the one compiled from Qt.

How to make Qt recognize openmp and how to enable the other optimizations in the command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp` instead of `LIBS += -fopenmp`.

Comment: Same. warning LNK4044: option '/fopenmp' non reconnue ; ignorée

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got all the required elements to get it compiled with openmp from Qt Creator:

1. Add `#include <omp.h>` to the source, which is not required if you compile with
   the command line mentioned above.
2. Add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -openmp` to the project file. It wont work
   with `-fopenmp`. No need for any openmp lib like I did ( `LIBS += -openmp` ) neither for `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -openmp`
3. Compile as release. With debug it has no impact on performance.

The other optimization options are already configured in `mkspecs\win32-msvc2012\
qmake.conf`

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I want to run *Qt* project with *openmp*. I have followed the above steps, I could build the project, but execution time is increasing instead of reducing.

Here is the configuration I used

```
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
#CONFIG -= qt
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -openmp
```